# OpenGL gluLookat not working with shaders on

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

When i want to use gluLookat and have the shaders on it doesnt move the "camera" when i turn the shaders off it works correctly.

Is there something missing in my shaders, i cant figure out what.

```cpp
void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.5,0,1,0.5,0,0,0,1,0);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 6, 6);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 12,6);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 18, 4);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 22, 6);
    glColor3f(1, 0.7, 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 28, 6);
    glFlush();
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```c
#version 450 core  // 420, 330 core , compatibility
in vec4 position

out vec4 Color;
void main()
{ 
 gl_Position = position;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```c
#version 450 core  // 420, 330 core , compatibility
in vec4 Color;
layout(location=0) out vec4 fColor;
void main() 
{
 fColor = vec4(0,0,0,0); 
}
```

Move the "camera" to where i want it to be with shaders on

Comment: @Rabbid76 What exactly do i have to tell the shaders to do and why do i have to use uniform ?

Comment: Technically you don't _have to_ use uniforms - any means of transferring the transformation data to the shader will do. Uniforms are just the most obvious way in this scenario, and also more or less the direct equivalent of what the implementation will do behind your back when it is emulating the more than 25 year old matrix stack crap which you are using here (which is deprecated for _over a decade_ by now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a shader program, then the vertex coordinate attributes are not magically processed, by the current matrices. The shader program has to do the transformations of the vertex coordinates.

---

You've 2 possibilities, either you use a compatibility profile context and use a lower glsl version (e.g. 1.10).

Then you can use the built in uniform [`gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLSL_:_recommendations#Built-in_Uniforms) (see [GLSL 1.10 secification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.10.pdf)) and the fixed function matrix stack will work:

```c
#version 110
attribute vec4 position

// varying vec4 Color;

void main()
{ 
     // ...  

     gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * position;
}
```

But note this is deprecated since decades. See [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) and [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL).

---

I recommend to use a library like [OpenGL Mathematics](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/index.html) to calculate the view matrix by [`lookAt()`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00668.html#gaa64aa951a0e99136bba9008d2b59c78e) and a [uniform](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)) variable:

```c
#version 450 core  // 420, 330 core , compatibility
in vec4 position

// out vec4 Color;

layout(location = 7) uniform mat4 view_matrix;

void main()
{ 
    gl_Position = view_matrix * position;
}
```

```cpp
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

// [...]
{
    // [...]

    glUseProgram(program);

    glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(0.5f,0.0f,1.0f), glm::Vec3(0.5f,0.0f,0.0f), glm::Vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(7, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view);

    // [...]
}
```

The uniform location is set explicite by a [Layout qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Explicit_uniform_location) (`location = 7`).
[`glUniformMatrix4fv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml) sets the value of the uniform at the specified location in the default uniform block. This has to be done after the progroam was installed by [`glUseProgram`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUseProgram.xhtml).

Comment: Great, Thank you, I used your suggestion and it worked like a charm.

Comment: the 2nd one, btw do you know any good Tutorial Site to learn OpenGL with GLSL from the start ?

Comment: @A.A. Probably there a lot of good tutorials and even more bad tutorials all over the web. But I can remember that [learnopengl.com](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Triangle) helped me a lot.